# How to find height, h, where line a is perpendicular to a circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I assume there must be a formula for this but couldn't find it.  Given a circle of known radius and line A that is tangent to the circle, another line is drawn perpendicular to the first at a distance (a) from where the tangent touches the circle. What is the distance (h) from where this perpendicular line intersects the first line, to where it intersects the circle?   How to work this out?
[image: How to work out h?]

This is what I tried so far:

Equation of circle: $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$

Given example circle where origin is x=0, y=0, and radius is 16 and tangent line is y = 16 and you want the distance where line x=12, ie line segment a length 12, then

$x = 12 \\ y=? \\ r=16$

$12^2 + y^2 = 16^2$

$y^2 = 16^2 - 12^2 = 112$

$y = \sqrt{112} = 10.58$

Therefore, $h = 16 - 10.58 = 5.42$

is that correct?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: @user619818: A property of segments product inside a circle is $ h(2r-h)=a^2\to h= r \mp\sqrt{r^2-a^2}. $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your method is correct. Here is a slightly different method that complements and confirms your method:

[image]

Referring to the above diagram and using Pythagoras, $y = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} \rightarrow \sqrt{r^2 - a^2}$.

$h \ = \ r-y \ = \  r-\sqrt{r^2 - a^2}$

For r=16 and a = 12 the result is $h \ = \ 16-\sqrt{16^2 - 12^2} \ \approx \ 5.41699$